# I do not want my text messages to sync between two iPhones

Tags: iphone, messages

My text messages are also appearing on my husband's iPhone.  How do I get them to not sync?

Comment: From Mac to iPhone or from iPhone to iPhone?

Comment: Can you add some more details about which devices are involved and with which iCloud accounts you are logged in in each of them?

Comment: See this thread and answer: [Separate Apple ID](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/84259/120171)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you sign out of your iCloud or Apple ID on his phone. If he is receiving your texts in iMessage, this means that both phones are sharing the same iCloud account (or apple ID)